# Why isn't the year in my citation call-out surrounded by round parentheses?

Tags: citing, natbib

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Gettier1963-GETIJT-4} 

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{Gettier}
\end{document}
```

The bibtex file, `Gettier.bib`, is:

```
@article{Gettier1963-GETIJT-4,
    volume = {23},
    doi = {10.1093/23.6.121},
    number = {6},
    author = {Edmund Gettier},
    year = {1963},
    journal = {Analysis},
    pages = {121--123},
    title = {Is Justified True Belief Knowledge?},
    publisher = {Analytica}
}
```

I would like the citation call-out to be `Gettier (1963)`, not `Gettier [1963]`.

Comment: `\setcitestyle{round}`, see the documentation of natbib.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer or `\usepackage[round]{natbib}`?

Comment: My understanding was that (1963) would be the default.

Comment: @daleif An attemt at using \usepackage[round]{natbib} crashed earlier. There must have been a misprint, as it works now!

Comment: @Sapiens I usually also have  the impression that round is the default. But sometimes I have to add the round option.

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but with `natbib` it is usually advisable to choose `\citep` or `\citet` instead of `\cite`, because the latter is more context sensitive for backwards compatibility reasons. (Page 4 of the `natbib` documentation says "The standard LaTeX command `\cite` should be avoided, because it behaves
like `\citet` for author–year citations, but like `\citep` for numerical ones.")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My understanding was that `(1963)` would be the default.

Not quite. In fact, as you've discovered, the default fence symbol type used in citation callouts is square brackets, *not* round parentheses, for `natbib`'s `plainnat` bibliography style. This also holds for the `unsrtnat` and `abbrvnat` styles.

If you want round parentheses -- `(` and `)` -- one of the following three methods will do:

- Specify the option `round` when loading `natbib`:

  ```
  \usepackage[round,<all other options>]{natbib}
  ```
- Run the instruction `\setcitestyle{round}` *after* loading `natbib`.
- (definitely the least convenient method:)

  Specify the first and second argument of the six-argument `\bibpunct` instruction as `(` and `)`, respectively:

  ```
  \bibpunct{(}{)}{<arg3>}{<arg4>}{<arg5>}{<arg6>}
  ```

  See page 12 of the `natbib` package's user guide for information about what the other four arguments of `\bibpunct` are all about.